# Downloading images with parse causes unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to download images from Parse and when I am finished downloading all images from parse my program crashes with the error:

> NSNull getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:progressBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I have tried adding some conditions such as

```
if(![object objectForKey:@"goal_image"]) //If it is nil => exit
```

But it is still crashing. Here is my code:

```
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Goal"];

        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[object objectId] block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

            if(!error)
            {
                PFFile * imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"goal_image"];
                if (imageFile) {

                    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error2) {
                        if (!error2) {

                            NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images/Goals/%@",[object objectId]]];
                            [data writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

                        }
                    } progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
                        if (percentDone == 100) {
                            NSLog(@"Download Completed");
                        }

                    }];
                }
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### tl;dr

You should check for `NSNull` aside from checking for `nil`.

```
PFFile * imageFile = object[@"goal_image"]; // note the modern Obj-C syntax
if (imageFile && ![image isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    ...
}
```

---

#### Explanation

`NSNull` is different from `nil`, the first one being an object.

Since `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` only hold objects, `nil` cannot be stored in such containers and that's why `NSNull` is used, typically to represent a `null` value returned in the JSON response.

Sending messages to `nil` fails silently, whereas sending an unrecognized selector to the `NSNull` singleton will result in a crash.

Also remember that `objectForKey:` will return `nil` in case the key is not found in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the explanation ;). I am new to iOS, less than a month,  and didn't know about this difference.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just in case anyone else is having this problem. For me, the above answer didn't work. What worked for me was enabling local datastore in app delegate. Honestly, not sure why this works, but I thought I should share

```
// Enable Local Datastore
[Parse enableLocalDatastore];
```